# How to set up an SQL Server authentication login for a database instead of using Windows Authentication

Tags: sql-server, authentication, users

Not sure what I am doing wrong so I have included the parameters I used which I used the existing login and this article for reference:
http://itproguru.com/expert/2014/09/how-to-fix-login-failed-for-user-microsoft-sql-server-error-18456-step-by-step-add-sql-administrator-to-sql-management-studio/
Whatever I do I get the Error: 18456 message.

[image: database user setup tabs]

Answer (score 1):

Ok found the answer after an hour of trying various options.

**Server properties - Security (see image)**

Shame there is no warning message somewhere when you create SQL Authentication users that they have no access.
[image]

Comment: There is a clear message in the error log:
Date  xxx
Log  SQL Server (Current )

Source  Logon

Message
Login failed for user ''. Reason: An attempt to login using SQL authentication failed. Server is configured for Windows authentication only. [CLIENT: <local machine>]